# Header DataLength com Arduino

Tags: java, c++, arduino, zabbix

Estou precisando de ajuda com o envio de um `HEADER`, produzido em `Arduino (C++)`, e enviado para um servidor `Zabbix`.

#### Documentação do cabeçalho

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/devel/manual/appendix/protocols/header_datalen

#### Meu Código em C++

```
Serial.println(json);
             int tamanho = json.length();

             String pacote = "";
             pacote = "ZBXD\1" ;
             String stringtres = String(pacote, BIN);
             String stringOne = String(, BIN);

             String separador = "\0\0\0\0";

             pacote += stringOne;
             pacote += separador;
             pacote += json;
             String stringtwo = String(pacote.length(), BIN);
             Serial.println(stringtwo);


           //Aqui conecto no servidor zabbix porta 10051
            if(client.connect(server, porta)){

              Serial.println(pacote);
              client.print(pacote);

              contador++;
              delay(5000);
     }
```

Exemplo de como o código deve ser feito em `JAVA`

```
byte[] header = new byte[] {
    'Z', 'B', 'X', 'D', '\1',
    (byte)(data.length & 0xFF),
    (byte)((data.length >> 8) & 0xFF),
    (byte)((data.length >> 16) & 0xFF),
    (byte)((data.length >> 24) & 0xFF),
    '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0'};

byte[] packet = new byte[header.length + data.length];
System.arraycopy(header, 0, packet, 0, header.length);
System.arraycopy(data, 0, packet, header.length, data.length);
```

Creio eu que esteja fazendo esse cabeçalho de uma forma errada, se alguém puder me ajudar fico grato!

Answer (score 0):

A implementação desse cabeçalho em C é bem parecida com a de Java.
Você vai precisa criar um array de char com o comprimento de 13 caracteres, sendo os 4 primeiros os caracteres 'Z', 'B', 'X', 'D', um caracter de controle 0x01, 4 caracteres para representar um numero de 32 bits de comprimento dos dados a serem transmitidos, 4 caracteres vazios no caso 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00.

Exemplo:

```
char header[13] = {
    'Z', 'B', 'X', 'D', 0x01,         
    (strlen(data) & 0xFF),
    ((strlen(data) >> 8) & 0xFF),
    ((strlen(data) >> 16) & 0xFF),
    ((strlen(data) >> 24) & 0xFF),
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

Comment: Correto consegui fazer a implementação do Header, tens ideia de como faço essa concatenação, tentei fazer aqui mas sem sucesso.
`code 
byte[] packet = new byte[header.length + data.length];

System.arraycopy(header, 0, packet, 0, header.length);

System.arraycopy(data, 0, packet, header.length, data.length);
`

Comment: Você vai ter de Instanciar um array de `char` chamado `packet` com o comprimento de `[len(data) + len(header)]` e usar o metodo `memcpy` para copiar para dentro de `packet` o array `header` e `data`.

Comment: Se você aceitar a resposta, o header zabbix vai funcionar cada vez melhor.